# Secure php source on shared server

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am using a shared server to host my php project and I want to secure my php source code so that no one can see it. The current permissions for files are `rw----r--` and for directories it is `rwx-----x` as the apache user is not in group. But with this permission anyone can see my code as everyone knows the location.

To prevent that I moved my application to an irrelevantly named folder and used `mod_rewrite` as followed

> RewriteEngine On
>       RewriteRule ^<application_name>(.*)$ <real_irrelevant_path>$1 [L]

Now everything works fine until I don't request an address like `<application_name>2`. It gives the 403 Forbidden error with message that `You don't have permission to access /<real_irrelevant_path>2/ on this server.` And the real path is exposed!

I know that I can use something like following. But I am not sure if it is fully secured.

> RewriteEngine On
>       RewriteRule ^<application_name>$ <real_irrelevant_path> [L]
>       RewriteRule ^<application_name>/(.*)$ <real_irrelevant_path>/$1 [L]

Now, my question is,

- What is the best way to secure these files?

Some notes,

- I can't use obfuscation as this is my development server.
- I don't have root access.

Answer (score 1):

Set the permissions to 750 and add the directory structure under the `www-data` group.

```
chown -R USER:www-data /path/to/web/folder
chmod -R o=,g+rx /path/to/web/folder
```

Replace `USER` with your username of course.

Using Apache config will only protect against web-based intrusion.  You still have to worry about FTP and SSH users.  That's where this comes in.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. But I don't have root access. It gives permission error.

Comment: If you own the folder you shouldn't have any permission errors.  Can you paste the console output into your post?

Comment: @nisargjhaveri you may not be using Drupal but you will no doubt benefit from this article:  https://drupal.org/node/244924

Comment: For the same command it gives `chown: invalid group: 'USER:www-data'`  and when I change group to apache it gives `chown: changing ownership of 'FILENAME': Operation not permitted` for each file and directory inside it

Comment: what is your output of `ls -l`

Comment: `drwx-----x. 4 USER GROUP 4096 Dec 22 19:36 public_html`

Comment: what about inside of that folder

Comment: the same for all directories and `-rw----r--` for all files with same USER and GROUP

Comment: try the commands I gave but without the `-R` option on the `public_html` folder, then try on one of the files inside that folder and report back

Comment: It gives the same error.